# I'm tryig to figure out how to create a menu that will allow me to restart the program when the option has been selected

Tags: java, menu, do-while

Hi so I'm new to coding but my dilemma is that I've created a  menu that has the following options for the user to either restart their game or to resume. I'm familiar with a do while loop, however I need the program to restart when the restart option is selected not at the end of the code. Is there a way I could break the code and have it restart the game, if so how would I go about doing this? (Also this is Java)

Comment: Also I'm incorporating multiple classes in this program if that changes anything.

Comment: I recommend you learn the basics first. Study fundamentals from  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Answer (score 0):

normally its bad style to use a **do{...}while(condition);** loop just use a normal **while** loop.
To break out of a loop you just need to use the **break** keyword:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            if (++counter < 5)
                System.out.println(counter);
            else
                break; 
        }
        while(true);
    }
```

this code above will run 5 times. So just write your program in there, break out and call the method again, in a way like this:

```
void run() {
    boolean breakout = false;
    do {
        // do your program
        if (breakout)
            break;
    }
    while(running);
    if (breakout)
        run();
}
```

Another way whould be something like this:

```
void run() {
    do {
        game();
    }
    while(running);
}

void game() {
    //do your game
    if (breakout)
        return;
    else
        //...
}
```

Comment: `normally its bad style to use a do{...}while(condition); loop` - who has taught you such a thing?

Comment: it just looks like you were to lazy to set the values of the condition before going into the loop. Of course is it simpler, and in some cases better, than using a normal while loop. 
Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Elucan - A `do-while` is as important as other loops. A `do-while` loop guarantees the loop execution at least once. I recommend you understand this concept better by writing some programs using both `while` and `do-while`. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to learn more about it.

Comment: Yes i know, but typically you can use a **while** loop for exactly the same and in my eyes its much more readable then the **do-while**. And I´ve said _normally_, cause I also had some cases when I used the **do-while** sometimes and of cause this one also has its right to exist, but maybe I just like the *while* more